# Server-side parser(?) for specified data

Tags: php

I'm learning php and website development in general. Currently I'm trying to write a script in php that would access a website as Internet Explorer (important) and look for a specified word/pattern everywhere possible. Simply parsing doesn't do the job.

The thing is, I can do that manually - I open website X and press F12 in Internet Explorer->debugging section and I search there. However I have no idea how to implement such a thing in php or any other language.

TL:DR
Need to extract data from a webpage the same way I do it manually (explained in paragraph above). However, simply parsing doesn't do the job. I need to achieve that in php or some other server side language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to limited approaches such as [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) followed by a string search (or [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)), you can look into more feature rich libraries such as the [SimpleTest Scriptable Web Browser](http://simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html).

You'll want to modify the user agent string in order to simulate a request from Internet Explorer.

Comment: Im playing around with "PHP Scriptable Web Browser" you mentioned and it might be a solution. Need more time to test it but thanks!